# CloudFront signed URL returns a 504

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I've got a chatbot backend which is talking to a service (service 3) which talks to another and sending a `CloudFront` signed URL for an image.

[image: Diagram 1]

Then from the Chatbot browser (client) requests to `CloudFront` which talks to `Service 1` and `Service 2` for serving the image.

[image: Diagram 2]

All the services are deployed in `AWS Elastic Beanstalk`. But now its reurning `HTTP 504` when requesting for the image from `CloudFront`.

[image: Error]

As a way of resolving this, I tried updating `Route 53` `CNAME` entry manually with `Service 1` load balancer URL assuming this has caused by `CloudFront` not being able to reach public DNS entry for `Service 1`. But it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: check cloudfront logs

Comment: cloudfront logs have not been enabled unfortunately